# Convert date format into MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: javascript, string, date, locale, date-format

I have dates that are outputted in this format:

```html
Thursday, October 11, 2018
```

I would need to convert it into

```html
10/11/2018
```

but first I'm struggling with getting rid of the day of the week (Thursday). Trying to look at other posts but cannot find something similar.
Thanks much in adnvace

Comment: show, what you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **[`Date#toLocaleDateString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)**.

Your code will be like this:

```js
var str = "Thursday, October 11, 2018";
let d = new Date(str);
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString("en-US"))
```

**Note:**

To get `10/11/2018` from the string `October 11, 2018` we need to specify `"en-US"` as `Locale` parameter of `toLocaleDateString()` method so we get the appropriate output, otherwise if you use it without a locale, it may return a wrong output if your time zone is different.

Comment: Parsing of the OP's format is also implementation dependent, there is not guarantee that it will be parsed correctly by the built–in parser. Also, the output of *toLocaleString* is implementation dependent, so there is no guarantee that it will produce the required format.

Comment: @RobG If it is implementation dependent, its the implementation that will guarantee this.

Comment: "Implementation dependent" means that each implementation can make up its own mind on how to deal with it and hence that the results may differ. The point is there is no guarantee as to the result across different implementations.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript can parse the date as supplied.

```
new Date("Thursday, October 11, 2018").toLocaleDateString("en-US")
// 10/11/2018
```

Comment: As method's name suggests, its result depends on user's locale if you call it without arguments (in my case it returns "11.10.2018")

Comment: @barbsan Well pointed out, that's why we should provide `"en-US"` as locale so we we make sure get `10/11/2018` as result.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit to include the locale - I read the question to be more regarding the parsing of the string, but you're right this wouldn't totally answer the question in an alternate locale

Comment: The OP's timestamp format is not consistent with those specified in ECMA-262, so there is no guarantee that it will be correctly parsed.